# Is Graphileon designed only for Neo4j or all graph databases?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graphics, graph-databases, graphileon

I am wondering if Graphileon is designed only for Neo4j or all graph databases?

Graphileon does not mention specifically for graph databases except Neo4j on their website. However, from all the tutorials I watched, they use Neo4j as underlying graph database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclosure : I am a member of the Graphileon team.

We currently support Cypher as well as openCypher. In practice, this means that we can work with [Neo4j](https://www.neo4j.com) and [Memgraph](https://www.memgraph.com) stores.

Our objective is to support a wide range of stores. After all, different graph stores have different "sweet spots" in terms of use cases and/or environments where they offer the best value.  That's why we currently are, in a joint effort with selected graph store vendors, making Graphileon work with Gremlin and Sparql. We expect to finalize this by the second half of 2019.

If you have a specific graph store that you would like Graphileon to support, please let us know.